# Cowboy multiple METHOD handler

Tags: rest, api, erlang, handler, cowboy

Trying to setup restful API via Cowboy
the main thing that I nedd to use one handler for all methods

here is router ::

```
 start(_Type, _Args) ->
    Dispatch = cowboy_router:compile([
        {'_', [
            {"/api", handler, []},
            {"/api/:id", handler, []}
        ]}
    ]),
    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(http, 100, [{port, 8080}], #{
        env => #{dispatch => Dispatch}
    }),
    api_sup:start_link().
```

and here is the handler code::

```
-module(handler).
-export([init/3, handle/2]).

init(_Transport, Req, []) ->
    {ok, Req, undefined}.

handle(Req, Opts) -> 
  case cowboy_req:method(Req) of
    <<"POST">> -> 
      Body = cowboy_req:has_body(Req),
      Request = postMethod(<<"POST">>, Body, Req),
        {ok, Request, Opts};
    <<"GET">> -> 
      #{id := Id} = cowboy_req:match_qs([{id, [], undefined}], Req),
      Request = getMethod(<<"GET">>, Id, Req),
        {ok, Request, Opts};
    <<"PUT">> -> 
      Body = cowboy_req:has_body(Req),
      Request = putMethod(<<"PUT">>, Body, Req),
        {ok, Request, Opts};
    <<"DELETE">> -> 
      #{id := Id} = cowboy_req:match_qs([{id, [], undefined}], Req),
      Request = deleteMethod(<<"DELETE">>, Id, Req),
        {ok, Request, Opts}
  end.

  postMethod(<<"POST">>, _Body, Req) -> 
    cowboy_req:reply(200, #{<<"content-type">> => <<"application/json; charset=utf-8">>}, <<"{\"status\": \"POST\"}">>, Req).
  getMethod(<<"GET">>, _Id, Req) -> 
      cowboy_req:reply(200, #{<<"content-type">> => <<"application/json; charset=utf-8">>}, <<"{\"status\": \"GET\"}">>, Req).
  putMethod(<<"PUT">>, _Body, Req) -> 
      cowboy_req:reply(200, #{<<"content-type">> => <<"application/json; charset=utf-8">>}, <<"{\"status\": \"PUT\"}">>, Req).
  deleteMethod(<<"DELETE">>, _Id, Req) -> 
      cowboy_req:reply(200, #{<<"content-type">> => <<"application/json; charset=utf-8">>}, <<"{\"status\": \"DELETE\"}">>, Req).
```

I am getting the error : cowboy 500 error

Comment: Do you get any errors in the terminal where you started this server?

Comment: nope, everything is ok when I starting the server

Comment: Deleted lager from the api_app.app and connection error gone. But now I facing 500 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.
here is the code which works fine (using master verison of Cowboy)

```
-module(handler).

-export([init/2]).
-export([content_types_provided/2]).
-export([content_types_accepted/2]).
-export([allowed_methods/2]).
-export([router/2]).

init(Req, Opts) ->
    {cowboy_rest, Req, Opts}.

allowed_methods(Req, State) ->
    {[<<"GET">>, <<"POST">>, <<"PUT">>, <<"DELETE">>], Req, State}.

content_types_provided(Req, State) ->
    {[{<<"application/json">>, router}], Req, State}.

content_types_accepted(Req, State) ->
    {[{<<"application/json">>, router}], Req, State}.

router(Req, Opts) -> 
  case cowboy_req:method(Req) of
    <<"POST">> -> 
        {<<"{\"status\": \"POST\"}">>, Req, State};
    <<"GET">> -> 
      {<<"{\"status\": \"GET\"}">>, Req, State};
    <<"PUT">> -> 
      {<<"{\"status\": \"PUT\"}">>, Req, State};
    <<"DELETE">> -> 
      {<<"{\"status\": \"DELETE\"}">>, Req, State}
  end.
```

Answer (score 1):

I came to a slightly different approach. Instead of going for `case` I use functions, pattern-match the method in request and then catch-all with code 405 Method Unsupported.

```
-module(handler).

-export([init/2]).

init(Req0, State) ->
  Req = case api:validate_headers(api_key, Req0) of
    ok -> handle(Req0, State);
    {error, Error} -> api:reply_failure(403, Error, Req0)
  end,
  {ok, Req, State}.

handle(Req0=#{method := <<"GET">>}, _) ->
  Data = "...", % Some data goes here
  api:reply_success([{<<"data">>, Data}], Req0);

handle(Req0=#{method := <<"POST">>}, _) ->
  Data = "...", % Some data goes here
  api:reply_success([{<<"data">>, Data}], Req0);

handle(Req=#{method := <<"OPTIONS">>}, _) ->
  api:reply_options(Req);

handle(Req, _) ->
  cowboy_req:reply(405, Req).
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of
`{Method, Req1} = cowboy_req:method(Req0)` is a tuple, like `{<<"PUT">>, _}`, not binary`<<"PUT">>`

Comment: Yes, I could see that in User Manual, but I dont understand why it's `<<"PUT">>` in cowboy echo_post example ::: [https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/blob/master/examples/echo_post/src/toppage_handler.erl]

Comment: This question for 99s team, use tuple

Comment: {Method, Req1} = cowboy_req:method(Req0) -- it was for 1.1.x version. Master version use binary now

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the router logic in the content_types_accepted/2 callback method like so:

```
 content_types_accepted(Req, State) ->
       case cowboy_req:method(Req) of
         {<<"POST">>, _ } ->
           Accepted = {[{<<"application/json">>, post_json}], Req, State};
         {<<"PUT">>, _ } ->
           Accepted = {[{<<"application/json">>, put_json}], Req, State}
       end,
 Accepted.
```

I think this way you can have separate handlers for different HTTP Verbs/Methods. This gives you cleaner code too :)